# Amazon Cloudwatch only receiving mem_used_percent and nothing else, despite numerous other metrics specified in config

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get CloudWatch running properly on my Lightsail instance, which I appear to achieved with only partial success.

I have ran the Wizard using `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard` which has produced a config file outlining numerous metrics including cpu, memory and disk usage as outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html). The service loads and starts the config file, and doesn't complain about invalid json (this did happen a few times, but I fixed it).

I can stop the service with `sudo amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop`

I then reload the config with `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -s -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json`

Verify the service is running: `sudo amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a status`

Which outputs this:

```
 {
  "status": "running",
  "starttime": "2022-01-10T21:53:12+00:00",
  "configstatus": "configured",
  "cwoc_status": "stopped",
  "cwoc_starttime": "",
  "cwoc_configstatus": "not configured",
  "version": "1.247349.0b251399"
}
```

Logging into my CloudWatch console, I can see the data being received, and the single line appearing on the graph there corresponds to the times that I started and stopped the service-- so it's definitely doing something. And yet... the only metric that appears on that graph is `mem_used_percent`... why? Why only this one metric? Where is the rest of my data pertaining to cpu, etc? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my config.json, which as I said, is being loaded by the service without issue.

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "ImageID": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId":"${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType":"${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "cpu": {
                "resources": [
                   "*"
                ],
                "measurement": [
                    "cpu_usage_active"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "totalcpu": false
            },
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                        "free",
                        "total",
                        "used",
                        "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                "resources": [
                        "*"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                        "mem_active",
                        "mem_available",
                        "mem_available_percent",
                        "mem_free",
                        "mem_total",
                        "mem_used",
                        "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "netstat": {
                "measurement": [
                        "tcp_established",
                        "udp_socket"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated here. TIA.

Comment: Did you have a look at the agent logs? Maybe some debugging is gonna help you there.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-no-metrics

Comment: @Riz thanks for your comment. I hadn't looked at those logs, no-- good to know, but seemingly not a lot of help in this case unfortunately. However, since posting this, some of the metrics have actually started showing up: seemingly there is some delay before they appear in the CloudWatch control panel. However, there are still issues; `cpu_usage_active` remains steadfastly absent from my graphs, despite being listed here as an available metric [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html).

Comment: ...meanwhile (having adjusted the original config.json in my OP slightly), `cpu_usage_user`, `cpu_usage_system`, and `cpu_usage_idle` all get recorded without any issue. I don't understand it, the docs are an obscure and convoluted mess, and I can't waste any more time with this. At least I've managed to get a basic graph of RAM usage which is what I needed. If anyone feels like enlightening me further on these issues it will be gratefully received.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test it. Yeah the docs are not very easy to follow. By the way, do you use `fetch-config` option when you change/modify the config file? On one place they tell you to restart to fetch new logs etc and on another place they ask you to use the fetch config option.

Comment: Thanks, @Riz. I do both: so I stop the service first with `sudo amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a stop` then load up new configs and restart with `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -s -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json`. Since restarting it I'm now not even getting anything at all related to cpu... seems to be luck of the draw which metrics actually arrive in my CW dashboard.

Comment: Hi @Inigo, One more suggestion. You can install(if already not installed) `collectd` which can collect metrics for you. Once installed, you need to put `"collectd": {},` above `"cpu"` .

Comment: @Riz Thank you! I will try this when I muster the willpower to look at this again, ha.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you face the same issue as I did. In my case two configuration json files

- `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json`
- `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json`

were merged.

The files are then translated to
`/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml`.

When I was checking the file, only the mem definition of `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/file_config.json` was taken. Thus, I deleted the file and restarted the service.

```
sudo systemctl restart amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

After the restart, the toml file contained what I expected and the metrics were in place.

Answer (score 0):

You likely haven't fetched the configuration yet.
Check the logfile, i.e. `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log`, to see which inputs are loaded:

```
2022-05-18T10:18:57Z I! Loaded inputs: mem disk
```

To fetch the configuration, do as follows (you'll need to adapt this to your environment - this is for systemd, on-premise, without SSM):

```
sudo amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m onPremise -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json
sudo systemctl status amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service restart
```

After:

```
2022-05-18T11:45:05Z I! Loaded inputs: mem net netstat swap cpu disk diskio
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, I realized I was looking at the wrong place.
You actually have to go back from graphs to:
Browse -> CWAgent

And you'll see that there is another box that is separate for all the different "folders" of configs: mem, disk, etc.

Hope this helps someone